# AttributeOverrides not working anymore after Upgrade to Hibernate 6

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I upgraded the following code from Hibernate 5 to 6.1.6 and get the following exception. It seems hibernate has somehow problems to iterate over the list of `AttributeOverride`s.

The main entity

```
package com.mypackage

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long myId;
       
    /**
     * The foreign key to the other table.
     */
    @AttributeOverrides(
    {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "column1", column = @Column(name = "column1", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "column2", column = @Column(name = "column2", nullable = false))
    })
    private OtherTableId otherTableId;
```

The composed foreign key

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class OtherTableId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "column1", nullable = false)
    private int column1;

    @Column(name = "column2", nullable = false)
    private int column2;

    public OtherTableId() {
        super();
    }

    public OtherTableId(int column1, int column2) {
        this.column1 = column1;
        this.column2 = column2;
    }
```

error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - EmbeddableMappingType(mypackage.MyClass.otherTableId.{inverse})#finishInitialization

    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.execute(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 97 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SelectableMappingsImpl.getSelectable(SelectableMappingsImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractEmbeddableMapping.inverseInitializeCallback(AbstractEmbeddableMapping.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.lambda$new$2(EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:108)
        ... 107 more
```

I could not find anything in the migration guide for hibernate. Do you have an idea what I have to adapt to make in run with Hibernate 6?

Comment: Please include the import statements for your entity (and the package).

Comment: I added the imports and package

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure you are using the right imports (and don't have some dangling `javax.persistence` imports). Could you also add the full stacktrace and what does your configuration look like? I do miss an `@Embedded` on the `otherTableId` field in the `MyClass`

Comment: I added `@Embedded`, but still the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following test in both Hibernate 6.1 and 6.2 CR2, and it succeeded:

```java
@SessionFactory
@DomainModel(annotatedClasses = {BTest.MyClass.class, BTest.OtherTableId.class})
public class BTest {

    @Test
    void test(SessionFactoryScope scope) {
        scope.inTransaction(s -> {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            OtherTableId otherTableId = new OtherTableId();
            myClass.otherTableId = otherTableId;
            s.persist( myClass );
        });
        scope.inTransaction(s -> {
            s.createSelectionQuery("from BTest$MyClass").getSingleResult();
        });
    }

    @Entity
    @Table
    public static class MyClass implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "MY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long myId;

        /**
         * The foreign key to the other table.
         */
        @AttributeOverrides(
                {
                        @AttributeOverride(name = "column1", column = @Column(name = "column1", nullable = false)),
                        @AttributeOverride(name = "column2", column = @Column(name = "column2", nullable = false))
                })
        private OtherTableId otherTableId;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class OtherTableId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name = "column1", nullable = false)
        private int column1;

        @Column(name = "column2", nullable = false)
        private int column2;

        public OtherTableId() {
            super();
        }

        public OtherTableId(int column1, int column2) {
            this.column1 = column1;
            this.column2 = column2;
        }
    }
}
```

So whatever is causing this error must be in code you're not showing us.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. My code works with 6.2 CR1 and CR2, but not with 6.1. So 6.2 seems to fix something I have been running into.

Answer (score 0):

@Marius comment seems to fix the issue.  Sadly this works

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
```

but later versions (I tried CR4) doesn't.

The latest version of Spring Boot (3.0.4 at the moment) is using 6.1.